# Karaf MSSQL not working

Tags: hibernate, jboss, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse, mssql-jdbc

I want to use Microsoft SQL DB in my bundle, and need to load entities.
 I have 2 bundles, one for datasource and another one for loading entities.
How to set the MSSQl datasource?

It is my datasource,

```
<bean id="esbDataSource" class="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource">
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb"/>
     <property name="username" value="sa"/>
     <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```

```
<osgi:reference id="platformTxManager" interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager"/>

<osgi:reference id="recoverableTxManager" interface="org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.RecoverableTransactionManager"/>

<!--<osgi:service id="pool" ref="datasourcePool" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" >
    <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/datasourcePool" />
</osgi:service>-->

<osgi:service ref="esbDataSource">
    <osgi:interfaces>
        <value>javax.sql.DataSource</value>
    </osgi:interfaces>
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/mssqlDatasource" />
    </service-properties>
</osgi:service>
```

Persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit name="billing" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/mssqlDatasource)</jta-data-source>

        <class>org.redhat.support.entity.Billing</class>
        <class>org.redhat.support.entity.Testing</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="testdb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I want to deploy this in OSGi karaf container, what settings i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got created tables and working fine. The below datasource is working fine.
Please double check needed dependencies should be installed in JBoss Fuse karaf OSGi container.

```
<bean id="esbDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```